# iam gettinig AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' while trying to split(" ") on text data

Tags: python, list

I am trying to vectorize the text data but am getting following **ERROR**

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

My Code:

```
yourResult = [str(sentence).split(' ') for sentence in tag_data["Tags"]]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(yourResult)#tag.apply(lambda x: str(x).split(" ")))
```

Comment: `lower` works only on strings, you are calling `lower` on a list.  Presumably it is a list of string, so there are two options. Either you can call `lower` on each element, or turn the list into a string and then call `lower` on it.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem is stated, `yourResult` is a list of lists, since `split(' ')` returns a list, while it should be a list of strings. `CountVectorizer` does splitting for you, so no need to do it in advance. This should work just fine:

```
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data["Tags"])
```

If you want to be in full control of how splitting works inside `CounVectorizer`, you can supply your own tokenizer:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda s: s.split(' '))
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data["Tags"])
```